# How to pass value JavaScript variable to PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Passing value JavaScript variable to PHP.

Example

**JavaScript**

```
Var ddd='aaaa'
```

**PHP**

```
if (ddd="aaaa"){do somehting...}
```

Comment: What are you asking exactly? You could submit a form or make an ajax request...

Comment: I would do an ajax request here.

Comment: Could you pass it in the URL to the PHP code, an ajax post to http://www.domain.com/?ddd=aaaa

A code example would be good!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is a Client side scripting language that is only executed after the page is fully loaded.
PHP on the other hand is an on-demand compiling script. It parses the PHP within the file and outputs the resulting HTML to the user's Browser.

Comment: not strictly true; Javascript can be executed while the page is loaded, if there's a `<script type='text/javacript'>` block within the `<body>` tag for example. To ensure Javascript executes after page load, it would have to be in a onload handler.

Comment: True, as the document is downloaded and generated, it parses any script tags methodically inline with the rest of the html. This allows you do to do things like `document.write('string');`

Answer (score 0):

In JS:

```
 $.post('ajax.php',{'dddd' : dddd}, function(data){
 });
```

In PHP

```
 if(isset($_POST['dddd'])) $dddd = $_POST['dddd'];
```

Comment: I really think you are not helping the OP by giving him a (jquery dependent) quick and dirty code without any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do that is to put it in the cookie:

```
var ddd = 'aaaa';
document.cookie = "ddd="+ddd; // the ddd in the "" is the name of the cookie
```

PHP

```
$ddd = $_COOKIE['ddd'];
if (ddd == "aaa") { do something... }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tested the following code and it have worked. So please test this code:

```
function aa()
{
    var ddd='aaaa';
    window.location.href="newpage.php?Result=" +ddd;
}
```

click a button then will  call `aa()` function and will go newpage.php where we get ddd variable value in Result variable

newpage.php:

```
extract($_GET);
echo $Result;
```