# Get Javascript value in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I made a javascript to get date, month, and year of today and it return my date time in "YYYY-MM-DD" Format. I want to get that date and set it in a php variable. How to do that?

Here is my script:

```
<script>
function date_js($date_js)
{
    var today = new Date();
    var day = today.getDate();
    var mon = today.getMonth()+1;
    var y   = today.getFullYear();

    $result-date=y + "-" + mon + "-" + day;
    return $result-date;
}
</script>
```

My php code:

```
<?php
   $date=date_js;
   echo $date;
?>
```

Is there anyway to get the value of my script in php?

Comment: JS is executed after PHP. You'll need ajax for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Passing value javascript variable to php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092553/how-to-passing-value-javascript-variable-to-php)

Comment: Fire an AJAX request.

Comment: If you just want current date, get it in php `$date = date('Y-m-d');`

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language which executes before Javascript.
So you can use php variable value to javascript variable, but can not use javascript variable value directly to PHP variable

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you pass a variable to a function and never use it? And why is there a function named the same as the param need? This is bad practice and can make great confusions. And yeah the correct way is to make and ajax POST with your variable and in your php code treat the variable like it would come from a form(with $date = $_POST['date'])

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { date: myDate}
})
  .done(function( data) {
    alert( "Date Saved: " + data);
  });
```

As for your php:

```
<?php

$date = $_POST['date'];
echo $date;

?>
```

The Ajax post script you can choose to be triggered by leaving the input(blur event) or you can choose to run it after a certain time(1 sec, 2 sec after user stopped typing). Hope it helps, code might not work by just copy paste but this is the way you should go. AJAX->PHP