# How to post a javascript variable to a PHP file to assign to a PHP variable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a webpage with several images. Each image can be replaced by an other image on the same place. Next to each image there is a form to upload the new image. 
Important is that the new filename must be replaced with a fixed name eg.: `cat.jpg` becomes `image1.jpg`, `dog.jpg` becomes `image5.jpg`, depending on the form used.
I use this html code for a first image:

```
 <div class="w3-padding-8 w3-card-8 w3-center w3-third w3-container ">
                <div class="w3-padding-8 w3-card-8 w3-center w3-container"><img src="images/cat.jpg" class="w3-padding-8 style="width:100%"></div>
                <div class="w3-center w3-container">
                    <form method="POST" action="upload4.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="file" multiple name="file[]" data-maxfilesize="5000000">
                        <input class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Submit 1">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

In the upload4.php I have this code to receive the new file. Now it assigns the name `images/image1.jpg` to it but I need a variable with the new filename in it.

```
<?php 
$sentfile = 'images/image1.jpg';
if (is_array($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$filename) {
        $uploadfile = $sentfile;
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k], $uploadfile)) {
            // ok
        } else {
            $error_message.= "Error while uploading file ".$filename."<br />";
        }
    }
} elseif(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    $uploadfile = $sentfile;
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        // ok
    } else {
        $error_message = "Error while uploading file ".$_FILES['file']['name']."<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

How do I assign `images/image1.jpg` to `$sentfile`?
I think I need **AJAX**? But how?
I know Javascript is client-side and php is serverside but how to communicate...

Comment: *"depending on the form used"*: what distinguishes between the different forms? They have different `action` attribute values? Or what else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass value JavaScript variable to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092553/how-to-pass-value-javascript-variable-to-php)

Comment: @trincot  the forms are all the same but I need to distinguish them by sending the fixed name maybe in the html between the divs with a kind of a datalink to a javascript file with a post command?

Comment: @Ankit Singh How to pass value is interesting but not helpfull to me. I am new in php ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont need ajax for this

First change the input tag to look like below:

```
<input type="file" onchange="getNewName_one(this.value)" multiple name="file[]" data-maxfilesize="5000000">
```

Then your create a function in JS:

```
<script>
function getNewName_one(str) {
  var break_path = str.split('\\');  // make sure the \\ is actually two inorder for it to work
  var len = break_path.length - 1;  // we need to get the last entry of the loop
  var filename = break_path[len]; // filename contains only the filename now;
  document.cookie = "newImageName_one="+filename;
}
</script>
```

Then update the php now

```
<?php 

$sentfile = $_COOKIE['newImageName_one'];  
?>
```

If your are having problems with the filename itself; like your are getting some wierd names in the input type="file" just comment it. Thank you.

Comment: thanks. When I insert the code as you mentioned without changing things, The file is uploaded with the old name in a strange way: on the server: C:\fakepath\cat.jpg. Where do I put the new name?

Comment: wow, I was expecting the C:\fakepath thing. But why the old name, did you use the onchange="", thing?

Comment: @backnext edited. Thanks. Anything else, let me know. ok.

Comment: I used your code: '<input type="file" onchange="getNewName(this.value)" multiple name="file[]" data-maxfilesize="5000000">' But I think the new file name must be inserted here but where?

Comment: Now I put in each form 'onchange="getNewName1(this.value)"', 'onchange="getNewName2(this.value)"', and so on. Then for each form a new function like this ' function getNewName1(str) { document.cookie = "newImageName=" + "images/1.jpg"; }' . That works but may be there is a shorter code possible?

Comment: Thank God, edited again. So you wouldn't have to manually type images/1.jpg again. since this is highly unpractical. Nonetheless I think after this code works consider Ajax, which I have put below

Comment: Thanx surge10!!! This works much better but with 'this.value' i get the existing name of the file. When I use the following code, it rocks... Now I will test your Ajax code. ' <input type="file" onchange="getNewName_one('images/1.jpg')" multiple name="file[]">'and in the next one 2.jpg...

Answer (score 1):

If i have understood correctly your question, what you are asking is to add a name to the image uploaded depending on the form used.

You could add

```
<input type="hidden" value="here goes the desired name of the image" name="desired name">
```

and then get the value through `$_POST['desired_name']`.

Comment: I'll try this... Do I have to place the '$_POST['desired_name']' in the php?

Comment: Well, if you want to get the value of the input, you must add the $_POST variable with the corresponding name from the input.

Comment: ok, another question: value and name will have the same content?

Comment: Well, **value** attribute is where you must put the desired name for the image, and then the **name** attribute is the one that you will use to access the value through PHP.

Comment: Example: `<input type="hidden" value="Name_image" name="form1">` Then, you will access through `$_POST['form1']` and you will get "Name_image".

Comment: So in my case it would be '<input type="file" multiple name="form1" data-maxfilesize="5000000" value="images/1.jpg">' ? (just before testing...)

Comment: I don't understand the POST thing: you say: $_POST['form1'] and you will get "Name_image". So this is in the php file I presume and I must do something like this: '$sentfile = $_POST['form1']' But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The new form:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" onchange="changeFile(this.value)" name="file[]" />
</form>
```

The JS:

```
<script>
    function changeFile(val) {

    var break_path = val.split('\\');
    var len = break_path.length - 1; 
    var filename = break_path[len];

    var ajaxCall = new XMLHttPRequest();
    ajaxCall.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if (ajaxCall.readyState === 4 && ajaxCall.status === 200) {
             var response = ajaxCall.responseText;
          }
      };


      ajaxCall.open("GET", "upload.php?fileName="+filename, true);
      ajaxCall.send();
    }
</script>
```

** you can use only one file upload.php ***

Then in the upload.php file:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['filename'])) {

$sentfile = $_GET['filename'];

}
if (is_array($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
  foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$filename) {
    $uploadfile = $sentfile;
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k], $uploadfile)) {
        // ok
    } else {
        $error_message.= "Error while uploading file ".$filename."<br />";
    }
   }
} elseif(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
$uploadfile = $sentfile;
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    // ok
} else {
    $error_message = "Error while uploading file ".$_FILES['file']['name']."<br />";
}
}

if($error_message != '') {
    echo 'Image Uploaded';
} else {
    echo $error_message;
}

?>
```

Comment: this Ajax solution doesn't work for me. It says 'Image Uploaded' but nothing happened. I don't know what's wrong.